# Do i need streaming replication slots as many of replicas in postgres?

Tags: replication, postgresql-9.6, master-slave-replication

Correct me if I am wrong but I’m thinking that if I have 4 different read only replica servers I need 4 streaming replication slots, one for each of them?
Or all of them can you use one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each replication slot requires a unique `primary_slot_name` in the `recovery.conf`, so you will need to have 4 connections for a streaming replication slot.